# Pre-render d3.js chart on the server and inject it into React

Tags: javascript, d3.js, jsx, jsdom

I have too much of data to visualize, so it makes `d3.js` very slow. I know that I can render the whole page on the server like it is described here with `jsdom`:

https://mango-is.com/blog/engineering/pre-render-d3-js-charts-at-server-side/

But what I really want to is to render just `d3.js` chart and 'inject' it into my `React` app. I am just confused because if I am rendering the whole page, then it is `jsx`, and `node.js` should also somehow see it since it is dynamically created. Are there any good libraries to generate `html` inside, say, a `div`-tag and then inject it on the front end into `jsx` `React` view? Any suggestions/links to tutorials/docs would be greatly appreciated.